# Button completely disappears when placed below gridview despite numerous configurations

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-button, android-relativelayout

I have a view in which i'd like a button to be placed below a grid view and fill up the remaining space. The view is a relative layout, and no matter what attributes I give it, if I some how relate the button to the grid view, it disappears. It only appears if I place it in the relative view with it aligned parent bottom, but then it doesn't stretch. The solution I thought would be most likely, though it didn't work either, was to place the button in the relative view, alignParentBottom=True and then layout_below="id/gridview" (all that is psuedo code). This is my code right now:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/pin_fragment_background"
    tools:context="com.lab125.viva_app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/audioPIN_marquee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/keypad_wrapper"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/audioPIN_marquee">
        <GridView
             android:id="@+id/keypad"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:columnWidth="90dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
             android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
             android:numColumns="3"
             android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

       <Button 
            android:id="@+id/start_ver_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Start_Ver_Button"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/audio_playback_btn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/keypad_wrapper"
        android:text="play"
        android:textSize="15sp">
    </Button>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Again, with this code, the button does not show at all.

---

Edit: @Dave's suggestion was correct, and I could see the button after setting the orientation to vertical. However, the only reason I had placed the gridView in a linear layout in the first place was in attempt to just not have the button disappear when having its android:layout_below property to the gridView (by setting its android:layout_below to something else). The more accurate fix for what I wanted to do however, was to not have the gridView's width and height set to match_parent, which was the root cause behind why the button was disappearing. So, i set the gridView's height to wrap content, but that caused the grid to shrink to the point where each grid element's content was no longer visible. I found that the cause of that was => I was programmatically setting the width and height of the gridview to wrap its content, and then the width and height of the components inside by the width and height of the parent view. Realized that was quite cyclical which may be why the gridview was shrinking when I set it to wrap content. I then set the width and height of the grid Elements based on the dimensions of the screen, which fixed the size of the gridView. So everything pretty much works now.

Here is my new layout, if anyone is interested.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/pin_fragment_background"
    tools:context="com.lab125.viva_app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" > 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/audioPIN_marquee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/keypad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/audioPIN_marquee"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/start_ver_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/keypad"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/Start_Ver_Button"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style" />

    <!--
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/audio_playback_btn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/keypad_wrapper"
        android:text="play"
        android:textSize="15sp">
    </Button> -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which button? and which direction are you trying to stretch it? is audio_playback_btn visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start_ver_btn won't show because the gridview has match_parent for both width and height, judging by your layout_width and heights, I think you want to set the LinearLayout's orientation to vertical.

Comment: Please post requests for clarification as comments.

Comment: Better? @bgenchel I could provide a better answer if you answer my questions in the comments.

Comment: the button labeled start_ver_button, and I'm trying to stretch it vertically. setting it to vertical did work, but now the dimensions of each grid component are out of whack. I have them programmatically set to be a certain percentage of the screen in height, but once they're in the linear layout, they no longer follow that. How can I resolve these two goals?